# Using ControllerAdvice from external jar

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I am trying to create exception handling module which could be used by multiple module. So I create jar which has all logic related to handling exception. I am trying to add global controller advice which could catch exception and generate error response .Problem is this controller advice is not getting invoked. 
It works fine when I write declare this controller advice in individual modules.

ExceptionHandling Module
    --ExceptionToResponseGenerator
MainModule
    --RestController
This doesn't work

ExceptionHandling Module

MainModule
    --RestController
    --ExceptionToResponseGenerator
This works

What am I doing wrong?

---

```
package com.abc.cde.exceptionhandler.handler;

@ControllerAdvice
@Log
public class ExceptionToResponseGenerator extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders httpHeaders, HttpStatus httpStatus, WebRequest webRequest) {
        return new ResponseEntity(new ErrorDetails(new Date(), "bad", "bad"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

---

Main class

```
    @Import(IncludeExceptionHandling.class)
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class MainApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }


}

-----------
IncludeExceptionHandling

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class IncludeExceptionHandling {

    @Bean
    public ExceptionLoggerPointcut notifyAspect() {
        return new ExceptionLoggerPointcut();
    }
}
```

---

ExceptionLoggerPointcut is aop wrapping exception and rethrowing it

Comment: Post code with package names, including the package name of your main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: @Strelok Have edited my post

Comment: You didn't post the package of your main class. ExceptionToResponseGenerator should be in the sub package of a package where MainApplication class is located or it will not be auto scanned.

Comment: Hi I am trying to achieve the same, please let me know if someone have resolved this

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the issue is with missing @ComponentScan. Please pass your code's package name and the external jar library name to the @ComponentScan annotation so that Spring can register the components and make them available to your App.